# How can I remove a potion effect with another potion?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I remove a potion effect by having a player throw a splash potion that removes it? Help?

Comment: Voting to close as so far you've shown us no real effort to try and solve the question yourself - you need to show at least some effort at attempting to do this, either by looking up commands or trying something.

Comment: @Crafter0800 You didn't vote. What close reason would you even choose?

Comment: @Superkaiyin It's impossible. Do something to trigger a command instead. Or make the potion have a really high level, but only 1 second duration. The main question is what you want to achieve with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. But if you take a sip from bucket of milk it will clear all buffs/debuffs.